Migrating to Android 13 App Data Retention
I am preparing a series of devices (Zebra specifically) from various previous versions of Android to Android 13. I became aware that through the migration tools used there would be app, storage and configuration settings lost in this process. As that is not an option I am wondering if there is any type of device cloning or possibly cloud storage to save that data? Any information on this would be helpful.
I have been going through the documentation provided which is how I was made aware of this issue. I am currently in the research phase as I am primarily an iOS user I am trying to become more familiar with Android so that I can solve this problem which is slightly time sensitive.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
